# How to read large csv as pickle in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pickle, computer-science

I am trying to perform analysis on dozens very large CSV files, each with hundreds of thousands of rows of time series data, with each file being about roughly 5GB in size.

My goal is to read in each of these CSV files as a dataframe, perform calculations on these dataframe, append some new columns to these dataframes based on these calculations, and then write these new dataframes to a unique output CSV file for each input CSV file. This whole process would occur within a for loop iterating through a folder containing all of these large CSV files. And so this whole process is very memory intensive, and when I try to run my code, I am met with this error message: `MemoryError: Unable to allocate XX MiB for an array with shape (XX,) and data type int64`

And so I want to explore a way to make the process of reading in my CSVs much loss memory intensive, which is why I want to try out the `pickle` module in python.

To "pickle" each CSV and then read it in I try the following:

```
#Pickle CSV and read in as pickle
df = pd.read_csv(path_to_csv)
filename = "pickle.csv"
file = open(filename, 'wb')
pickle.dump(df, file)

file = open(filename, 'rb')
pickled_df = pickle.load(file)

print(pickled_df)
```

However, after including this pickling code to read in my data in my larger script, I get the same error message as above. I suspect this is because I am still reading the file in with pandas to begin with before pickling and then reading that pickle. My question is, how to I avoid the memory-intensive process of reading my data into a pandas dataframe by just reading in the CSV with pickle? Most instruction I am finding tells me to pickle the CSV and then read in that pickle, but I do not understand how pickle the CSV without first reading in that CSV with pandas, which is what is causing my code to crash. I am also confused about whether reading in my data as a pickle would still provide me with a dataframe I can perform calculations on.

Comment: I don't think the reading method is the issue. You're probably running out of memory because the dataframe is too big.

Comment: Hmmm that makes sense, but I was trying to use the "pickle" instead of such a dataframe. Or is my understanding of what pickle is used for wrong? I thought I could have a memory-light "pickled" dataframe instead of the pandas dataframe that I can do my calculations on. Or can I not do operations on the pickled dataframe?

Comment: Pickle is a format for saving data in the file, it has nothing to do with how the data is represented in memory.

Comment: Oh, I see, Ok. Perhaps I should not be trying pickle then, and need to find another way to make my dataframes less memory intensive. Thanks for clarifying this for me.

Comment: You need to find a different algorithm that doesn't require processing everything at once.